# Access UDF with Variable Field Names

Tags: ms-access, vba, naming-conventions, user-defined-functions

32Bit Access 2013 / Win 7 64bit

Function Prompts for a table name and two field names, depending on data in the second field something will be entered into the first field.

```
Public Function FillTableGaps(TableName As String, Field1 As String, Field2 As String)
```

In Different tables these Fields, Field1 & Field2 could be anything so I need them to be dynamic.

```
CTbl![Country] & CTbl![State]
'was replaced by
CTbl![Field1] & CTbl![Field2] 'respectively
```

Now I just need to be able to pass "Country" and "State" as Field1 and Field2 to read/write to those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider brackets, for example:

```
CTbl(Field1) & CTbl(Field2)
```

Comment: I tried to play with this, what I'm looking for is basically `Variable = CTbl(Field1)` where Field1 is the string name of a field. So that later I can call `CTbl!Variable` and return a value as I loop through the CTbl elements

Comment: Okay, I'm with it -- use CTbl(Field1) instead of CTbl![Field1] -- that'll work, thanks.